# Multiple InternalResourceViewResolver for Spring 5.0.6.RELEASE

Tags: xml, spring

We have a different setup on tomcat, each webapp consist of multiple project under them. so we have a webapp that has multiple spring projects under it.

The view jsp's are not in one folder , but in multiple folder as below:
WebApp1/A/Views/JSP/
and 
WebApp1/B/Views/JSP/

How can we serve the view using a multiple InternalResourceViewResolver, right now looks like only one is supported.
Have tried below options, but it is not working:

```
<bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="WebApp1/A/Views/JSP/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="WebApp1/B/Views/JSP/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Refer to this https://dzone.com/articles/chaining-url-view-resolvers

Comment: @Palsri could not find the class ChainableUrlBasedViewResolver in Spring 5 release.. Is there any xml  example ?